# Should I edit an answer to add to it, even though the current answer is sufficient?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, etiquette

This revolves around this question/answer: [Backup workitems on VS Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041901/backup-workitems-on-vs-team-services/34158683#34158683).

I've used the answer and was able to get it to work, but in VS Team Services there's "Discussions" on work items that are not included in the standard JSON returned by the API, you have to do another call to retrieve them.

**I was wondering if I should edit the answer to include links to getting the Discussion History, since I believe it would be helpful for anyone who finds it. Or just mention them in a comment?**

Comment: Unless the answer is a Community Wiki, i'd suggest using comments.

Comment: You could add a complementary answer that details the missing information for your specific case.

Comment: The help center says that one reason to edit is to "add addendums", "add related resources or hyperlinks" and "include additional information only found in comments". I would say it's fine to edit.

Answer (score 3):

In general it is better to comment on the answer than add completely new information to the existing answer, especially if it was not explicitly asked for in the question (unless it is "Community Wiki).

Alternatives:

- if information is requested in the question - feel free to add new answer that explains new part. Link to existing answer and provide one-line summary.
- consider if new question & self-answer would be better. Link back to the existing question from the new one and add a comment to the existing question to check new question.

In this particular case I'd post new Q&A pair like

> How to store VSTS discussions
>   I'm trying to save VSTS work items with corresponding discussions. I found existing answer [Backup workitems on VS Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041901/backup-workitems-on-vs-team-services/34158683#34158683) but it does not cover discussions.

If you decide to go this route make sure there is no easy to find existing answers. Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-answer for general guidance on self-answered questions.